# Template is not shown on the server

Tags: python, html, flask, server

I am very new to Flask and Web development so sorry in advanced if I use incorrect terms.

I am trying to create a webpage using Python and Flask. To do so, I have the following:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_assets import Environment, Bundle

app = Flask(__name__)
assets = Environment(app)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
     # Code to do the login
     error = None
     if request.method == 'POST':
         # code checking the passwords. if correct:
         return render_template('index.html')
         # else:
         #    error
    return render_template('login.html', error = error)
```

What this snippet of code does is to load the `login.html` where the user is asked to put an username and password and after checking if they are the ones expected, it loads `index.html` where the user can upload his or her data. Once the data is submitted a new function is called:

```
@app.route('/transform', methods=["POST"])
def transform():
    f = request.files['data_file']
    if not f:
        return "No file"
    # code
    return render_template('message.html')
```

The problem is that while in local the `message.html` gets display once `transform` has finished, in the server it doesn't appear although the function eventually does what it's expected to do. The other two templates are correctly displayed both in local and in the server. Could it be due to be in a different route?

The `index.html` is defined with `action='\transform'`, in case it may give a hint.

Any idea of why could this be happening?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the server it doesn't appear "? What is your definition of local and server?

Comment: What do you mean by " in the server it doesn't appear although the function eventually does what it's expected to do. The other two templates are correctly displayed both in local and in the server." ?

Comment: When server I mean that I executed in a web app, while in local I use localhost:5000.